# Detect if javascript dialog button clicked and redirect

Tags: javascript

Hey guys, I am showing a javascript dialog box to user using window.onbeforeunload to handle if user clicks back button.
My code is working to a point, but I am struggling to redirect the user if they click 'Leave this page' (Message varies in different browsers).

```
// Set check var false to begin with
// This is set true on submit btns using onclick event
submitFormOkay = false;

// If we are on check-availability page
if( window.location.href.indexOf( 'check-availability' ) != -1 )
{
     // If back button is clicked
     window.onbeforeunload = function()
     {
          // Only show dialog if submit btn wasn't clicked
          if (!submitFormOkay)
          {
               // Show dialog
               return "Use of the browser back button will lose form data.\nPlease    use the 'Previous' button at the bottom of the form.";

               // If 'leave' this page was clicked'
               // do 'window.location = window.location'
          }
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 0):

If they click "Leave this page" then the browser will complete whatever action the user was trying to perform before the dialog popped up.

But if they do navigate Back, they will still be on your site, right?  So you can just do whatever you need to do when that page is re-requested (providing it's not cached).

In other words ... detect on server-side if the user has clicked Back, and then do whatever you would have done if they had clicked Previous.

Comment: Hi joey, thanks. I was hoping to be able to detect using javascript. I guess I can do what you've suggested, just means I have to hack back into this drupal form api again!

Comment: Thank you for your help Joey, I didn't mean to sound unappreciative there!

Comment: No problem.  Unfortunately you cannot override the user's behaviour, if they decide to ignore your warning.  But at least you got to warn them, so whatever happens is their own fault!

Comment: One option you could pursue, is to post a message to the server when the onbeforeunload first gets called (either by adding a new <SCRIPT> to the page, or using XMLHttpRequest).  That way your server will know that the user tried to navigate away.  But that is probably overkill if you are working on the Drupal anyway.